# Permalink Rewrite for Custom Taxonomy

Tags: url-rewriting, taxonomy

I have added a custom taxonomy called 'Boards' with the following code

```
function add_custom_taxonomies() {

    register_taxonomy('board', 'post', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Boards', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            ~snipped~
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'board',
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
    ));
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomies', 0 );
```

If I have 2 boards with the same name "My Board", the urls will be
1) mydomain.com/boards/my-board/
2) mydomain.com/boards/my-board-2/

I would prefer to use the board/term ids so that the urls are
1) mydomain.com/boards/15/
2) mydomain.com/boards/16/

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few parts to making this work.

First, we register the taxonomy:

```
function wpa69163_register_txonomy() {
    register_taxonomy('board', 'post', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Boards', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'board',
            'with_front' => false
        )
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa69163_register_txonomy', 0 );
```

Next, we have to add a filter to `term_link` to generate the URLs with `term_id` for our tax terms:

```
function wpa69163_term_link( $termlink, $term, $taxonomy ){
    if( 'board' == $taxonomy )
        return home_url() . '/board/' . $term->term_id . '/';
    return $termlink;
}
add_filter( 'term_link', 'wpa69163_term_link', 10, 3 );
```

And last, we have to intercept any queries for our tax terms and convert the `board` query var from ID back to slug so WordPress is able to load the correct posts:

```
function wpa69163_boards_query( $query ) {
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['board'] ) ):
        if( $board = get_term_by( 'id', $query->query_vars['board'], 'board' ) )
            $query->query_vars['board'] = $board->slug;
    endif;
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpa69163_boards_query' );
```

Comment: Works perfectly!